# alamofire upload array of images doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire

I need to upload an array of images with some extra text. I used Alamofire like this:

```
  let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(userToken)"]
            Alamofire.upload(.POST, "url", headers: headers, multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                if let post = post?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: post, name: "name")
                }
                if let pictures = pictures {
                    for image in pictures {
                        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)?.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength) {
                            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "pictures", fileName: "pictures", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                        }
                    }
                }
                if let pictureText = pictureText?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: pictureText, name: "picture_text")
                }

                }, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
                            DDLogDebug("Uploading images for status post \(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
                        }
                        upload.responseJSON { (response) in
                            let json = response.result.value
                            DDLogDebug("Status post complete \(json)")
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                                handler(result: json, error: nil)
                            })
                        }
                    case .Failure(let encodingError):
                        DDLogError("Failed to post: \(encodingError)")
                        handler(result: nil, error: NSError(domain: "failed response", code: 123, userInfo: nil))
                    }
                }
            )
        }
```

Now the problem is that the server wants an array of images and gives us the error Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0. So there is something wrong on the upload code but I can't figure out what. In postman it's just an array and it works fine. I thought when I loop through the pictures and give the the same name it would act like an array.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the index to the filename this is the solution

```
  if let pictures = pictures {
                for (index, image) in pictures.enumerate() {
                    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
                        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "pictures[\(index)]", fileName: "picture", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                    }
                }
            }
```